# How to config synced folder with nfs in vagrant

Tags: configuration, vagrant

```
config.vm.synced_folder configuration["projects-folder"],
    "/var/www/projects", create: true, group: "www-data",
    owner: "www-data", :mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=666"]

config.vm.synced_folder "./localhost", "/var/www/localhost",
    create: true, group: "www-data", owner: "www-data",
    :mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=666"]
```

My configuration file looks like above. If I wanted to use nfs for these folders, would I do that inside the mount options? Just add nfs=true inside mount options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the type as nfs - see https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/nfs.html#enabling-nfs-synced-folders

```
config.vm.synced_folder "./localhost", "/var/www/localhost", type: "nfs"
    create: true, group: "www-data", owner: "www-data",
    :mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=666"]
```

Comment: When I tried this it didn't work because those are not valid [nfs mount options](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/819-1634/rfsrefer-16/index.html). I don't think it's possible to set permissions this way with an nfs share, unless someone can show me a different way?